# What website(s) can I use to plan an IFR route along airways? WORLDWIDE

Tags: flight-training, software

I'm looking for a good website where I can create a IFR route including the airways. I tried route finder but it doesn't give me the airways.

Comment: What country are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for a website for the whole world including Europe.

Answer (score 1):

## For the United States, [Skyvector](https://skyvector.com/) is easy and free.

Use the buttons in the top-right corner to switch to "World Lo", that will give you instrument charts.

Comment: It shows the airways, but it doesn't seem to want to generate routes in Europe.

Comment: @CrossRoads My guess is that it pulls routes from the FAA Preferred Routes database, and the FAA doesn't concern themselves with Europe.  That's just a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

Try Skyvector.com. Try "World Lo" for the map view. Select Flight plan, enter Start and End locations, select Routes. Select one of the route options that appears.  Edit the routing if you want to change (or add) airways or intermediate airports.